# Using github.com to get the data into servers in private subnet in the aws VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, github, ansible

We are building a web application which will have some servers in the public subnet and some in private subnet. The code will be kept on www.github.com/somerepo which will be pushed to the servers through ansible whenever there are any changes. 
Since now the github repo is sitting on the internet and our servers are in private subnet. How do we make sure that that the code is pushed from github to these servers. I have an idea to use a NAT gateway, but i am unsure on how to place it in the VPC.

Comment: It may be worth taking a look at CodeDeploy here. For outbound access from your VPC's private subnets, read https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

Answer (score 0):

You could either user [HAproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to receive the GitHub [hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), this instance will be in the public subnet within an elastic IP.

Based on your setup this instance may be available to send/forward the requests to an instance within your private-subnet, so the flow may look something like:

```
github --->  x.x.x.x/10.0.1.X/24 ---> 10.0.8.X/21
                     |                     |
              EIP/public-subnet      private-subnet
```

An [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing) could also work, but you will need also an instance to handle the requests.

This will help to get the "events" sent by the defined hooks, in where your deploy application could then do your desired logic and deploy within your subnets.